# Modification of const int through a non-const pointer

Tags: c, pointers, constants

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(){
    const int a = 10;
    *(int*)(&a) = 9; // modify a
    printf("%d", a);
    return 0;
}
```

- When I run this code on Xcode, the output is 10 (not changed)
- When I run this code on Visual Studio Community, the output is 9 (changed)

Why?

Comment: The better question would be: why are you trying to modify `const` value instead of learning something useful. It's against the language.

Comment: It's UB. Look at the generated assembly code or step through the code in disassembly mode.

Comment: @REACHUS sounds reasonable

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> *Q: why?*

Ans: [undefined behaviour](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Undefined_behavior).

To explain, if you try to modify a `const` variable value by accessing is through some `non-const` pointer, it invokes [undefined behaviour](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Undefined_behavior).

As per `C11` standard, chapter 6.7.3, paragraph 6.

> If an attempt is made to modify an object defined with a const-qualified type through use of an lvalue with non-const-qualified type, the behavior is undefined.

Note: The recommended signature of `main()` is `int main(void)`.

Answer (score 8):

This program would compile but exhibits undefined behavior and may output `9` or `10` or something else or may crash who knows.

When you say `a` is `const`, you promise that you won't try change the value of `a` directly or indirectly and compiler may make certain assumptions. If you break the promise unexpected things may happen.

Answer (score 0):

const keyword is used not to change the value of variable. If its done forcefully results may be unexpected